# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'images/38564af7conno.PNG' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found) react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using react js to upload images in firebase alongside its post contents so far I have managed to upload an image and its doc but the problem is when I try to put image URL along doc it says the image does not exist and when I check back in my console account I find the uploaded image

down below is my upload codes

```
const createPost = async () => {
if(image == null){
  const cover = "default";
  await addDoc(postsCollectionRef, {
    title, 
    postContent, 
    created_at,
    cover,
    author: {name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid} 
  });
}else{
  const cover = addOn+image.name;
  const storage = getStorage();
  var storageRef = await ref(storage, `images/${cover}`);
  const upload = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,image,image);
  upload.on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert);
  await getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(function(url){
    console.log(url);
    
  
  addDoc(postsCollectionRef, {
    title, 
    postContent, 
    created_at,
    cover: {cover, url},
    author: {name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid} 
  });
  });
}
navigate("/");};
```

If I can get relevant examples it will be very helpful some says that the problem is that i am calling url before the image is not upload so i tried to add await but still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanksful to [image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029611/how-to-replace-a-loading-image-in-a-chat-with-an-image-uploaded-to-firebase-stor)
that i saw where the problem was it was so simple as I was not considering code flow arrangement

if you come across this problem know that you should take image url inside the then() function as you can see the chane in my codes below

```
else{
  const cover = addOn+image.name;
  const storage = getStorage();
  var storageRef = await ref(storage, `images/${cover}`);
  const upload = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,image,image).then(
    () =>{
      getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(function(url){
        console.log(url);
        
      
      addDoc(postsCollectionRef, {
        title, 
        postContent, 
        created_at,
        cover: {cover, url},
        author: {name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid} 
      });
    }
  );
  });
}
```

Thank you very much for the participating